# Tag manager plugin with separate insert and view mode

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a jQuery or JavaScript tag manager plugin which allows to show tags in two modes:

1. Insert: which is exist and is default in all tag manager plugins (I want to use this functionality in admin page)
2. View: to show only tags, not the input and delete icons (I want to use this mode to show tags to users and visitors - without the ability to change tags)